# Puppeteer, Laravel Sail, Macbook M1

Tags: laravel, puppeteer, apple-m1

I have a Macbook Pro M1 MAX and I am using Laravel sail to scrape data, or that is what I am trying to do.

I ran in to issues installing puppeteer due to chromium not being arm64 ready:

```
The chromium binary is not available for arm64.
```

so I did the following.

I installed `spatie/browsershot` and ran

```
sail PUPPETEER_EXPERIMENTAL_CHROMIUM_MAC_ARM=1 npm i puppeteer
```

and this time everything installed.

I added the ExecuteJavascriptMiddleware to:

```
public array $downloaderMiddleware = [
    RequestDeduplicationMiddleware::class,
    ExecuteJavascriptMiddleware::class
];
```

and the middleware is firing fine but I get this error:

```
Error: Could not find expected browser (chrome) locally. Run `npm install` to download the correct Chromium revision (1022525).\n
at ChromeLauncher.launch (/var/www/html/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ChromeLauncher.js:70:23)\n
at async callChrome (/var/www/html/vendor/spatie/browsershot/bin/browser.js:84:23)\n
```

Even though when I look in node_modules/puppeteer I can see:

[image]

Anybody come across this and found a solution?

Comment: Where you able to resolve it? I'm currently trying the same thing

Comment: @mxmtsk not yet, how about you?

Comment: Were any of you able to figure it out? I'm also trying to get this setup to work, no luck yet.